# how to run .net application when i want to run i got error system.net.socket.socketException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

i am new in .net i have application here when i run in windows i got error like this one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwLWW.jpg)

System.Net.Sockets.socketException found why like that ?how to fix this problem here ?

and this is my c# program when getting error

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net;


namespace TrialCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] urls = new string[] { "http://localhost:9900" };
            if (File.Exists("urls.txt"))
                urls = File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt");
                var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls(urls)
                .UseStartup<Program>()
                .Build();
            webHost.Run();
            
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Information);
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}

namespace TrialCheck
{
    public class Trial : Controller
    {
        [Route("ping")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Ping()
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return Ok(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        [Route("loginid")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoginId()
        {
            try
            {
                string str = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
                string res = TradingAPI.MT4Server.LoginId.Decode(bytes, 0).ToString();
                Console.Write(".");
                return Ok(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                return new NoContentResult();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

i have download .net framework and .net core from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download i have update and add the following and add following package for run it and it can be run. but when i want to run i got error

Comment: have you tried using a debugger and placing breakpoints? or atleast tried to print to the console? Exceptions are used when unexpected things happen in the program. This is a socket exception so check if you setup the socket(s) correctly

Comment: Exception tells you that kestrel tries to run under given url's - and those are invalid. Please review your urls or edit question and past it. For future - please also put exception message as text - you are lucky that I click on link to image and checked.

Comment: oh i see i got the point because of wrong urls here thanks all

Comment: If you have worked it out please answer your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

after i check my source code my problem is when i run the program.exe the program search urls.text and after i see there there is any ip are not in my laptop so i delete it and change to be my ip